# Framework not found OpenSSL

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When i try to build on my real device i am getting this error from xCode

ld: framework not found OpenSSL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to remove Pods folder and Podfile.lock and run pod update with no luck, anyone face same issue?

OS: macOS 10.15.7
Xcode: Version 12.4
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2

Comment: having same issue

Comment: @ДанилаНиконец did you solved it?

Comment: I was trying so many things. I created a new project and moved code and libs there step by step. ios version was bumped from 10.0 to 11.0. Don't remember what exactly help me with this issue (i had some more)

Answer (score 0):

After many changes and searches, I did something simple and it's working fine with me, I changed the IOS version in the Deployment Info section to IOS 13.0, and working fine with me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuy42.png